# 404 after setting output of Azure Function to Cosmos DB

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I use site editor for Azure Function. I modified initial function code, so it is now:

```
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"

using System.Net;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
{
    string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();

    log.LogInformation(requestBody);

    return new OkObjectResult(requestBody);
}
```

then added an output to Cosmos Db using output parameter `$return`

when I'm testing my function I get 404 and nothing else

has anybody faced this issue and what can be done?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I have set 2 output bindings to my function. Initially it was bound to HTTP and I have added Cosmos Db. I removed HTTP output binding and now it works like a charm

Comment: Yes, the same issue I found when I was using two out bindings with the same name. must have a unique name for in and out bindings.